# Why I get "QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread" messages if I have no QTimer in my code?

Tags: python, pyqt4, multiplatform, qtimer

When (and only when) I quit my application, these (and only these) repeated message appear on the command prompt:

```
QObject::startTimer: QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread
QObject::startTimer: QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread
QObject::startTimer: QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread
```

This is quite strange for me, because I never use QTimer in my code (or QThread).
In fact, no errors or crashes happen using the application, so this is not a real problem, actually.
This happen in both Windows and Linux OSs.

All my imports:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from PyQt4.QtGui import (QApplication, QMainWindow,
                         QFileSystemModel, QTreeView, QTableView,
                         QAbstractItemView, QMenu, QAction, QKeyEvent)
from PyQt4.QtCore import QDir, Qt, SIGNAL, QString, QFileInfo, QCoreApplication
import sys
```

The main function:

```
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("QFM")
    app.setStyle("plastique")
    gui = MainWindow()
    gui.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Perhaps it could be something related to QFileSystemWatcher (used by QFileSystemModel), I guess...maybe it uses some QTimer features.

Comment: Can you point out on which line of your code these messages are caused?

Comment: Absolutely not, this 2 or 3 repeated lines are the unique information that are given to me!!! :-|.

Comment: Try adding some console output to find the causing code line.

Comment: Maybe it comes from a library you use. Try to eliminate parts of your code until the problem goes away. That should give you some clue where the problem lies.

Comment: @user714965: there is _no_ other console output, it's not possible to find the causing code line.
JanneKarila: I added my imports. Because the application is still very small, I'm going to go test previous versions to find the moment when the issue started to appear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PyQt4 Results in QThread error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995367/pyqt4-results-in-qthread-error)

Comment: Without a SSCCE this question is basically impossible to evaluate. -1

Answer (score 11):

I've had similar problems in the past.

The `QFileSystemModel`[documentation page](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qfilesystemmodel.html) says the following:

> `QFileSystemModel.__init__ (self, QObject parent = None)`
>
> The parent argument, if not None, causes self to be owned by Qt
>   instead of PyQt.
>
> Constructs a file system model with the given parent.

If you don't pass a `parent` argument then the Python garbage collector can delete the object at the wrong time and as a side effect raise the error you mention. My advise is to make sure that your objects have a proper parent. I think it should fix the problem.

PS: I haven't checked the docs for every class you use. Maybe `QFileSystemModel` is not the only class on which this thing happens.

Comment: I hit the same problem with ``QCompleter`` class

Answer (score 3):

In my experience this happens when I subclass a Qt class and one of the members of the subclass is not part of the Qt hierarchy. For example:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ...
        self.my_widget = MyWidget()
        ...
```

If I implement `MyWidget` in this way, it will give me the `QTimer` error when the object is destroyed:

```
class MyWidget(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # do stuff
```

However, if `MyWidget` inherits from `QObject` then no error occurs:

```
class MyWidget(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        #do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

pass in self into the instantiation of it if you are not subclassing it like so
QFileSystemModel(self)