# Remove warnings from the console

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, warnings, elementtree

How to remove warnings such as following warnings from the console:

```
 QObject::startTimer: QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread
 QObject::startTimer: QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread
 QObject::startTimer: QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread
```

Update: It is just a guess that it raises because I am using ElementTree to parse an XML document into an element tree:

```
    def parse(source, parser=None):
   tree = ElementTree()
   tree.parse(source, parser)
   return tree
```

I would appreciate if you guide me which other parser other than ElementTree i can use..

Comment: Do you mean in general, or just QObject-related warnings?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda it's a warning message from Qt that is posted in _runtime_ if something goes wrong.

Comment: It is shown in my console when i close the Qwidget window. Yes, I mean how to resolve this specific warning from console..

Comment: Do you spawn threads in other ways than creating QThread?

Comment: I am using an ElementTree to parse an xml file, can that raise the problem?

Comment: Why don't you post some more (related) code?  It will be hard to diagnose your situation otherwise.

Comment: Look on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562501/why-i-get-qtimer-can-only-be-used-with-threads-started-with-qthread-messages-i) and maybe some other related questions which are found right on this site.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a warning, it's an error, and you should not "remove it", you should *fix it*. 
It happens because you use QObjects from threads that were not started from a QThread. Probably you're using native python threads. Use QThread instead, and you'll be fine. The XML stuff is a red herring, it seems irrelevant.